# Facebook forcing a redirect

Tags: wordpress, facebook

For some reason, Facebook is picking up on a redirect on my posts which is leading to issues with sharing.

Take a look: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Then try this URL in the debugger: http://punsdepot.com/pun/22

What's odd is if I change the permalink structure to use the post slug, it doesn't redirect.

I disabled all plugins to see if it was plugin related and found nothing. I also tried a couple of redirect detectors and everything seems to come back as a normal 200 response.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your site _does_ redirect to `http://punsdepot.com/pun`, which gets served with an HTTP status code 404 and has only the text _“Bots get the naked version”_ on it, when the `User-Agent` of the request is that of the Facebook scraper (easy enough to test f.e. by using Modify Headers extension in Firefox) … so you do still have some kind of plugin running, or some .htaccess rules or something similar that specifically causes this behavior. Go investigate …

Comment: Can I ask how you found that it does redirect? I used several online tools to detect a redirect and it came up with nothing...

Comment: Like I said … by sending the `User-Agent` header that the Facebook scraper uses with the request. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#scraperinfo

Comment: Missed that...sorry. Trying to do more than one thing at once.  Thanks for the help!